# how to fill a composite object using java reflection?

Tags: java, class, reflection, field, getter-setter

I have a config file like this:

`Provider Search,ConfigURL,http://myUrl`

I want to fill this object using reflection

```
public class MyPrefrences {

    public ProviderSearch ProviderSearch;
}



    public class ProviderSearch {

        public String ConfigURL;

    }
```

here is my code, but I fail to set the composite object:

```
    MyPrefrences myPrefrences = new MyPrefrences();

    try {
        Field field = myPrefrences.getClass().getDeclaredField(normalizedCategory);
        Field field2 = field.getClass().getDeclaredField(normalizedKey);
        field2.set(field, val);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
```

how would you do it

a) if all leaves members are String?

b) if I the leaves can be primitives and non-primitives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all You need to pass your Object reference which value you want set in `field.set()`.

And second: field.getClass() gives you `java.lang.reflect.Field`, use `field.getType()`to get Class you need.
So, it should be like this

```
Field field1=myPref.getClass().getDeclaredField("ProviderSearch");
Object obj=field1.getType().newInstance();
Field field2=field1.getType().getDeclaredField("ConfigURL");
field2.set(obj, "www.stackoverflow.com");
field1.set(myPref, obj);
```

Comment: I tried this code and it works for me. In your Exception configURL start with lowercase 'c' and in  getDeclaredField with UpperCase.Check your field name

Answer (score 0):

The providerSearch must not be null in myPreference's instance.

```
MyPrefrences myPrefrences = new MyPrefrences();

try {
    Field field = MyPrefrences.class.getDeclaredField("ProviderSearch");
    Field field2 = ProviderSearch.class.getDeclaredField("ConfigURL");

    field2.set(field.get(myPrefrences), val);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

In addition, I recommend:

- Don't use public field.
- Use variables that begin with lower case.
- Use getters and setters.

Comment: still fails java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: configURL on this line: `ProviderSearch.class.getDeclaredField("ConfigURL")`;

Comment: Java is case-sensitive. ConfigURL is different to configURL. Check your code.